# Password protected access to phone features

Tags: password-protection

Is it possible to password protect access to certain phone features s.a. ability launch google-play (to install new apps), and certain apps ?

Is it possible to restrict ability of a phone to make phone-calls or send/receive SMS's to/from particular set of numbers, under password control ?

User experience would be that they are prompted to enter a password/secret-PIN to access these features. If user enters the correct password/PIN they get access to the specific application otherwise not.

*Edited (Sept 19, 2012):*
Looking for solution that does not require flashing custom ROMs. Thus MIUI, Aliyun, Cyanogen-Mod etc. are not feasible, as I require the solution to work on the ultra low-cost Android devices which use Mediatek chipsets.

Comment: can you disclose the reason why you need the blocking, is it for cost control, privacy, or security? (different reasons would have different best solution) Many operators have parental control features that allows you to monitor and block phone calls and SMS. That might be suitable for you?

Comment: Apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free&hl=en does half of your requirements like blocking app without password.

Comment: @LieRyan, the reasons are "Parental Control" indeed, but in case where operators currently does not provide such service, or subscriber does not intend to pay a monthly recurring fee for such service, since it could potentially be done on a phone itself.

Comment: @roxan, thanks for replying. As you can see below Web-E has already provided that suggestion. Good to have a reinforcement though.

Comment: lol, totally didn't see this from review mode. Also totally forgot I had already commented with similar suggestions :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Smart App protector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free&hl=en) or similar software. However I haven't tested it personally. I use MIUI rom which have these functions built in.

Comment: Thanks @Web-E. Looks like a locking-app that cannot be fooled or circumvented (at least not easily). As for MIUI ROM, I was under the (incorrect) impression that it is UI-only enhancements, but looks like it's more than that. Alas, it is not available on the ultra-low-cost Mediatek chipset based sub $100 phones.

Comment: Shall wait a little more, and if there are no better suggestions, will probably accept this an an answer, although it does not address the need to have a black-list or white-list of numbers that I could call.

Comment: @icarus74: There are several apps in the market that claims to be able to restrict outgoing calls, you might want to check them out. I don't know how easy they are to subvert though, so I can't give any recommendations.