# How can I hide an application from the app drawer?

Tags: applications, app-drawer

I've got Micromax Canvas 2 and have installed one application which is having some confidential data. Now I want to hide that application from menu.

Is there any way / application for that?

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29475/password-protected-access-to-phone-features

Comment: Hi Flow, I'm not looking for an app to lock other apps. I want to hide selected application from menu.

Comment: I know, that's why the question did get closed as duplicate. :) I wonder how you would then start your app if it's now shown in the app drawer (and anywhere else).

Comment: Obviously, from an app we've listed out as hidden. It should be work as simple as image / video locker.

Comment: it would be more logical, if the application itself would require a password..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different launcher, like [ADW launcher.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher) Free, and has that function.
On the downside, it consumes a bit more of RAM.

Comment: Hi csomakk, thanks for the reply. I need an application.

Comment: its an application.